# What is the role of question mark here "Class<T?>" in C#?

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
var x = new Class<T?> {...}
```

My question is: what is the role of question mark there?

Comment: It specifies that `T` is a nullable type.

Comment: Suggests this is a nullable value type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: It can be either nullable reference type or nullable value type, depending on `T` constraint